# aspcud fails with "could not lstat file"

Tags: linux

`aspcud` is an external solver recommended by ocaml's `opam` package manager. Unfortunately, it is only packaged for Debian; for other distributions there is a tarball with binaries available from [the sourceforge page](https://sourceforge.net/projects/potassco/files/aspcud/).

Simply copying all the binaries to somewhere in your path (e.g. `/usr/local/bin`) and running `aspcud` fails with an uninformative error message:

```
$ aspcud
error: could not lstat file
```

[Posting this mostly so that "could not lstat file" gets some google hits; the only hit right now is someone else who ran into the same issue.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `aspcud` looks for the other files it depends on in either `.` or in the explicit prefix it was invoked with (i.e. if you call it via `aspcud` it will look for `gringo` in `./gringo`, but if you call it via `/usr/local/bin/aspcud` it will look for `/usr/local/bin/gringo`) rather than in `$PATH`. So rather than copy the binaries to your path, copy the entire tarball to `/opt` or similar, and then have an `aspcud` executable shellscript in path invoking it with full path

```
#!/bin/bash

/opt/aspcud-1.9.1-x86_64-linux/aspcud $@
```